# "If none of this is clicking for you yet, it is not clicking for me, either."

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This is from [the transcript of a podcast.](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/1081508190)

> ALLYN: ...Mark Zuckerberg's version of the metaverse, everyone is
> legless and just a floating torso. And I don't know. I kind of like my
> legs. I'm a pretty good runner. I mean, how - if I'm in the metaverse
> without legs, I lose my best asset. I don't know.
>
> SANDERS: If none of this is **clicking for** you yet, it is not **clicking
> for** me, either. So I called up both Bobby and Shannon to make the
> metaverse make sense for me and for all of you. Also, we should
> mention right here that Facebook, or Meta, that company has been a
> sponsor of NPR. And while we're at it, so have Google, Microsoft and
> Apple - companies you'll hear mentioned later in this chat.

I wonder what 'click for' means in the above context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we suddenly understand something (especially if it has been puzzling us) we can say that it 'clicked' (in our heads, comparing our brain with a mechanical device, where a part can click or snap into place).

I couldn't work out how Joe got home, and then it clicked! He owns a bicycle!

> click verb (BECOME CLEAR)   C2 [ I ] informal
>
> to be understood, or become clear suddenly:
>
> *Suddenly everything clicked and I realized where I'd met him.*
>
> *As he talked about his schooldays, it suddenly clicked where I had met
> him before.*
>
> *So it's finally clicked that you're going to have to get yourself a
> job, has it?*

[Click (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/click)

Comment: Thank you very much.